# Rails -- utility of params.permit() outside of mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The rails documentation for [permit](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/permit) states that it "is useful for limiting which attributes should be allowed for mass updating"

Is there any other utility? Say security?

Answer (score 2):

The entire point of having `.permit` for security reasons. As of Rails 3.0, Rails uses what's called a whitelist approach when it comes to parameter mass-assignment. What this essentially entails is that all parameters are not allowed by default, and you have to manually allow which parameters are allowed to be mass-assigned.

This prevents a hacker from using certain parameters, i.e.: if you have an admin parameter that checks whether an admin is present and  that also accepts a boolean value, a hacker could just write in the parameters, admin=true, and potentially gain access to your app's ability to create, update or delete certain components to your detriment.

So the key to preventing this, is using strong parameters to only allow parameters which you want to be mass-assigned. In doing so, this would avoid the potential pitfall of letting a hacker have access to parameters you don't want to be used. You do this with `.permit` in combination with `.require`.

Comment: But how does that help anything? If you aren't *using* the admin parameter, then how would it get into your database anyway?

Comment: Strong parameters are to prevent that hypothetical situation, in which you are using something like an admin parameter. Strong parameters don't necessarily need to be used in 100% of cases, but Rails forces you by default to use them, as a best practice, just in case you did have a parameter that could be manipulated by hackers. There are numerous other ways you could be hacked, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting, but having strong parameters such as `.permit` prevents being hacked through manipulating parameter usage.